# Multiple remove selected items listview

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm going crazy to understand where is the problem in my code. I'm tring to remove multiple items from listview, more precisally, remove the selected items. I wrote this code.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(requestCode == 1) {
        try {
            for(int a=0; a<adapter.getArrayPositions().size(); a++) {
                applicationInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(adapter.getList().get(a), a);
            }
        } catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            for(int a=0; a<adapter.getArrayPositions().size(); a++) {
            appInfoArrayList.remove(adapter.getArrayPositions().get(a));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            }

    }
    else {

    }
}
```

My method getArrayPositions() return correctly the items position but it remain in the Listview. Why? why they are not removed?

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getArrayPositions() {
    return myArrayList;
}
```

Comment: What type is your `applicationInfo` variable?

Comment: ApplicationInfo applicationInfo. Is correct?

Comment: Mmh, so, where is the problem in my code? I don't understand because the items remain in the ListView.

Comment: I'm working on it now

Comment: Thank you very much. If you find a solution please post it. Thanks again.

Comment: How you do instantiate appInfoArrayList? This has the same references the list inside adapter?

Comment: could you also post the adapter code?